# React native send a message to specific whatsapp Number

Tags: reactjs, react-native, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a text message to a WhatsApp contact from a react-native apps , i found that i can do it through Linking

```
Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?text=hello');
```

the code above opens only whats app , i need to open a chat with a specific number is there a paramter i have to send like text ?!

Comment: whatsapp://send?abid=\(ID)&text=hello

Comment: this opens only screen sharing and ask me to choose which account i want to share my message with ! i need to open a direct chat with specific user

Comment: also can you show my the format of abid ?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use this to send a message to specific number:

`Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?text=hello&phone=xxxxxxxxxxxxx')`

Comment: Hi, what about linkedIn! I'm the same for linkedIn profile

Comment: How to send image along with text

Comment: How to send to WhatsApp business

Comment: Hi, How can i share specific text or data  in other social media like facebook, twitter, pinterest, google plus etc.

Comment: @ShaileshPrajapati i think the same link open the available one on mobile or option to select one if both available

Comment: How does one find all of the Linking URL possibilities?

Comment: Is there some way to specify multiple phone numbers in the link?

Answer (score 7):

**share message to whatsapp to a specific predefined number independent to platform**

```
sendWhatsApp = () => {
  let msg = "type something";
  let phoneWithCountryCode = "xxxxxxxxxx";

  let mobile =
    Platform.OS == "ios" ? phoneWithCountryCode : "+" + phoneWithCountryCode;
  if (mobile) {
    if (msg) {
      let url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + msg + "&phone=" + mobile;
      Linking.openURL(url)
        .then(data => {
          console.log("WhatsApp Opened");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          alert("Make sure WhatsApp installed on your device");
        });
    } else {
      alert("Please insert message to send");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Please insert mobile no");
  }
};
```

Please Note: send + in front of phone with country if opening in android

Comment: it works without + too now in android as well as ios

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method to send whatsApp message direct to a number.

**Example link: https://wa.me/919234567812?text=%7B0%7D+Balaji+CTest**

```
export const sendWhatsAppMessage = link => {
 if (!isUndefined(link)) {
  Linking.canOpenURL(link)
   .then(supported => {
     if (!supported) {
      Alert.alert(
        'Please install whats app to send direct message to students via whats 
         app'
      );
    } else {
      return Linking.openURL(link);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
} else {
  console.log('sendWhatsAppMessage -----> ', 'message link is undefined');
 }
};
```

Comment: The API url can be this: `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+31612345678`