# How to switch account when deep linking from another app to whatsapp?

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, deep-linking, whatsapp

I have WhatsApp (version 2.23.23.78) installed with multiple accounts, one for personal & the other for business

[image]

And I'm [deep linking](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/CqmCX0YvQGM) from my own react native app to WhatsApp [as such](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521103/22302305):

```
Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?phone=${client_phone_number}&text=${auto_generated_msg}`);
```

This works fine and directly opens the client's chat with the message pre-typed & the only thing left to do is press the send button:

[image]

However if I was previously logged onto my personal account the client inbox is opened from there

Is it possible to modify the deep link such that whenever WhatsApp is opened from my app it always switch to the business account (or asks which account to switch to) when sending a message?

---

**Note**
I'm also open to a [share sheet](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share) solution using a [dual app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9U5Tnhqqn0o) if it can achieve the same thing i.e. opening the client chat and pre-typing the message